# How can I redirect my page to previous page or controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Someone might have asked this, but I can't find it. I use CodeIgniter right now. How can I redirect my page to previous page or controller?

```
function lihat($kode_matkul){
    $data['absen'] = $this->absen_model->absen($kode_matkul);
    $data['main_content']   = 'tambah_absen';
    $this->load->view('page', $data);
}

function tambah($nim, $kode_matkul, $hadir){
    $tambah = $this->mhs_model->create($nim, $kode_matkul, $hadir);
    redirect('absen/lihat/$kode_matkul'); //the error line
}
```

The problem is that after I use `tambah` function, I want to redirect my page to `--->base_url()/absen/lihat/` (the `kode_matkul` here), but the program just redirect me to `--->base_url()/absen/lihat` and `kode_matkul` I get from MySQL row. Thank advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use double quotes to make variable visible by php, because single quotes do not recognize php variables inside a string. Another way is joining string with variable through '.' (dot) operator:

```
redirect("absen/lihat/$kode_matkul");
```

or

```
redirect('absen/lihat/'.$kode_matkul);
```